# need to find the min distance and make a route

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

The graph:

[image]

and how the points are connected:

[image]

the file how points are connected are the output i have . The expected output should be `1<->216 , 23<->157 115<->157` and then `115<->216` . The order doesn't matter but those points should be connected this way

Let me ask you a question. 
I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.size()-1;i++)
    {
        int result = 0;
        double Min2 = DBL_MAX;
        int x = 0;
        for (int j = i+1; j < values.size(); j++)
        {


            /*if (visited[j] == false)*/

            {
                distance = sqrt(pow((values[i].x2 - values[j].x2), 2) + pow((values[i].y2 - values[j].y2), 2));

                if (distance < Min2 && distance != 0)
                {

                    Min2 = distance;

                    x = j;
                }

            }

        }
```

If you look at the graph the left first node is 1 then goes 216 then 115 then 157 and then 23. I have the right connection except for 216-115 but instead of it connects 216-157. Why does it ignore or min distance won't help. I tried to use flag( like if visited or not)the same result. All nodes work , just this one doesn't want to be connected right.

Comment: what you describe in the question (order of nodes: 1->216->115->157->23) does not match at all what is in the image "how points are connected".

Comment: ... "how points are connected" is the output of your code?

Comment: the first image is the graph with points
the second picture are points how they are connected. It doesn't matter if points are connected from 1-216 or from 216-1 .. Main is that all points should be connected and all of them are connected right except for 115-157 becase the code connect 157-216
What you said 1->216->115->157->23 it is how graph represent . I added those points to vector and it can be that first goes 1 then 23 but i can't sort them because it is how it should be . The idea is just i need to connect them right and the code connects and i have even more points and they are right

Comment: what is the expected output and what is the output?

Comment: the expected output should be. 1->216 23->157 115->157 115->216 and can be 216->1 157->23 157->115 216->115
 My output is 1->216 23->157  115->157 and then 157->216 it overflows 115

Comment: please edit the question to make clear what is the expected output and what is the output you get. You still didnt answer what is in the image "how points are connected"....

Comment: I have already answered. I have   1->216 23->157 115->157 and then 157->216
Need to have 1->216 23->157 115->157 115->216
You can see the distance between the fourth node and the second node is longer than between the third and second but it overflows the third and connected fourth and second
And that image represents my output

Comment: so, "how the points are connected" is the output, right? You really should edit the question to include expected output and the output you get (am I repeating myself?) in the question. Did you debug the code? What are the coordinates of the points?

Comment: [0] = {x2=1447920.0363159201 y2=4789279.9377441397 }
[1] = {x2=1454810.0471496601 y2=4788439.9414062500 }
[2] = {x2=1451952.1836399999 y2=4788788.3581130002 }
[3] = {x2=1453378.2878739999 y2=4788614.4944770001 }
[4] = {x2=1449779.2860250000 y2=4789053.2671360001 }
vector[0] has the point 1 , vector[1] has the point 23 , vector[2] has the point 115 vector[3] has the point 157 and vector[4] has the point 216

Yes that file is my output

Yes i debug it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I read but yes sorry but really i need help if you can try it and then send me what you get . Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of the code seems a bit odd...

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.size()-1;i++) {
    int result = 0;
    double Min2 = DBL_MAX;
    int x = 0;
    for (int j = i+1; j < values.size(); j++) {
```

iterating till `size()-1` seems like you assume that the relation "closest neighbour" is commutative, but it is not. Consider this example:

```
a  b                           c
```

a has b as closest node and (by chance) also b has a as closest node, but c has b as closest node and this connection you would miss.

Further, starting the second loop at `i+1` seems rather odd, as it assumes that the points in the vector are already ordered (if this would be the case, then whats the point of searching the closest nodes?).

If you know already, that the nodes are along a route, then I would do it like this:

1) start with the first node `n0` in the route (its a bit more complicated if you dont know this node)

2) find the closest node to `n0` call it `n1`

3) continue to find the closest node to `ni` among the nodes that are not yet connected to the route, call it `ni+1`

4) repeat 3) until you reach the end of the route.

I have the impression, that you dont understand the difference between those steps and your code. I dont like to give up, so I will try to explain again in a less pseudo way:

```
int currentNode = startNode;     // as mentioned before, if you dont know 
                                 // this its a bit more involved
std::vector<int> route;
route.push_back(currentNode);    
while (currentNode != endNode) { // also knowing the last node of the route helps...
     double minDistance = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
     int nextNode = -1;
     for (int i=0;i<nodes.size();i++) {
         if (std::find(route.begin(), route.end(), i) == route.end()){
             double distance = getDistance(currentNode,i);
             if (distance < minDistance) {
                 minDistance = distance;
                 nextNode = i;
             }
         }
     }
     route.push_back(nextNode);
     currentNode = nextNode;
 }
```

Your outer loop shouldnt iterate through all nodes, if you actually want to find only that one route. Also you have to remember nodes that are already in the route (in case each node should appear only once and you dont want a closed loop).

Comment: Yes you are right and i did it but the results are the following. 
1->216    23->157   115->157   157->115 and then 115->216
I didn't use that method because it creates me two times the same route

Comment: And that's why i wanted to use visited flag but it gives the same output as previous

Comment: @MishaOstapchuk you did what? (and please stop spamming sequences of numbers)

Comment: ok sorry  You sent me that answer , i changed and got that output that was posted the first after your answer .. The problem i have here it duplicates me the same routes twice not just with this points but with all

Comment: @MishaOstapchuk you changed what? I just stated that I dont understand the logic of your code, but I cannot tell you how to fix it. Already your assumption that by finding the min distance alone you can make a route is wrong (see edit in a second).

Comment: the logic of my code is simple. I go to the first node and check it with all the same nodes in the second loop then find the min distance and it finds me the right route. I have a map with all route in python and i can check , the problem is just one . You told me to not use size()-1 and j start with 0 . I did and i have duplicates for example as you stated a has b and by chance b has a and i don't need it. If i use flag , i have the right route also but here is just one line wrong.. That's why i can't understand how to fix it

Comment: No, I didnt tell you what to do! I just told you that the code you posted looks odd to me.

Comment: ok i just changed size()-1 , because j i should start with 1 at least otherwise it gives me some unimportant results. Ok i will try to think tomorrow maybe find a solution because there should something be changed

Comment: @MishaOstapchuk I edited once more, hope this finally helps

Comment: that is what i need to impelement. I created visited but it doesn't give the right connection because it ignores one line. For example after first iteration it gives me that node 0 connects with node 1 how can i start exactly with node 1 in the next iteration. And actually it ignores because then i start with a node but not with the node that has been just connected

Comment: @MishaOstapchuk what "line" ? You dont show how you use that flag, thus I dont know how to help

Comment: @MishaOstapchuk I edited once more ( never had such an ugly answer before ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.size();i++)
    {
        int result = 0;
        double Min2 = DBL_MAX;
        int x = 0;

        for (int j =0; j < values.size(); j++)
        {


            /*if (visited[j] == false)*/

            {
                distance = sqrt(pow((values[i].x2 - values[j].x2), 2) + pow((values[i].y2 - values[j].y2), 2));

                if (distance < Min2 && distance != 0)
                {

                    Min2 = distance;

                    x = j;
                }

            }

        }
        /*visited[i] = true;*/
```